# Error: Cannot find module '@firebase/app' when deploying in Firebase functions

Tags: firebase, angularfire2, angularfire

I recently started a new project and using `AngularFire` for firebase hosting. Some days back AngularFire team did an incredible job and rolled out the one liner for deploying Angular SSR app to firebase hosting/functions.

Everything was working well till the moment I added FirbaseAuthModule and now it giving me the `Error not able to load @firebase\app module`. Not sure if anybody encountered the error while deploying to firebase.

I did the steps as mentioned here in the `AngualrFire` doc - https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/deploy/getting-started.md

I use `ng deploy` for hosting/functions in firebase (this is not working)
I use `ng deploy --preview` for local testing (this is working)

In one of the issues reported a year back it was mentioned that you need to install firebase and angularfire to the /functions also but now this is generated by `AngularFire` every time you do `ng deploy` so I am kind of stuck here.

```
Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module 'firebase/app'
     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
     at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
     at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
     at webpackUniversalModuleDefinition (/srv/dist/server.js:3:28)
     at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/dist/server.js:10:3)
     at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
     at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
```

My package.json dependencies are as follows

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^9.0.0-beta.29",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/localize": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^9.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~9.1.0",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.6.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.28",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^9.1.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^12.1.2",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "firebase": "^7.13.2",
    "ngx-image-zoom": "^0.6.0",
    "ngx-img-zoom": "^4.1.2",
    "ngx-pagination": "^5.0.0",
    "ngx-spinner": "^9.0.2",
    "ngx-swiper-wrapper": "^9.0.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.5",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "^0.900",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.901.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^9.1.0",
    "@nguniversal/builders": "^9.1.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.10.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.6.0",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.1.7",
    "firebase-tools": "^8.0.1",
    "fuzzy": "^0.1.3",
    "inquirer": "^6.2.2",
    "inquirer-autocomplete-prompt": "^1.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Looking at the source code, looks like your issue has been fixed](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/src/schematics/deploy/actions.ts#L107).

The script currently takes the externalDependencies listed in angular.json for the server build and add it to the functions package.json. When deploying the cloud functions, Google cloud will install all these dependencies and your SSR will work (locally it already does because you have firebase in your node_modules).

The approach works but I personally prefer to have my own functions folder, in this way I can also add other functions and I have more control over my code. I just had your same problem and I simply installed firebase into my functions to have the deployment working. [I'm doing some boilerplate with Angular, Tailwind, HMR, SSR and Firebase if you want to take a look.](https://github.com/michelepatrassi/ng-starter)

Answer (score -2):

Try "npm i @firebase/app" it seems like that package is missing [link to package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@firebase/app)